# Camel testing with Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing, apache-camel

In ["Camel in action"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182366) book I found this test example:

```
@Test
public void testMoveFile() throws Exception {
    // create a new file in the inbox folder with the name hello.txt and containing Hello World as body
    template.sendBodyAndHeader("file://target/inbox", "Hello World", Exchange.FILE_NAME, "hello.txt");

    // wait a while to let the file be moved
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    // test the file was moved
    File target = new File("target/outbox/hello.txt");
    assertTrue("File should have been moved", target.exists());

    // test that its content is correct as well
    String content = context.getTypeConverter().convertTo(String.class, target);
    assertEquals("Hello World", content);
}
```

Obviously It is an integration test - we test more than one unit, but:

- Are tests like that (with Thread.sleep) considered as good practice?
- Can we do better, leaving integration test approach
  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its chicken and egg. As in the Camel in Action book, later we introduce you to NotifyBuilder which allows you to test without the thread sleep. See chapter 6, section 6.4.2.

There is also some details about NotifyBuilder on the Camel web site
http://camel.apache.org/notifybuilder.html

Comment: I always knew stackoverflow is great :) Thanks Claus - btw. very nice book.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Big Al. You shouldn't use Thread.sleep if you can avoid it and if you do (which happens to be quite common when testing front-end behaviour) you definitely want to loop for a set time and fail if it hasn't completed in X milliseconds.

Using thread sleeps tends to, in my opinion, create a fragile or slow test suite. You can't guarantee whether an environment will run the tests in a particular amount of time.

Also, I would suggest that you don't use unit tests to check whether a file has been moved or not. This means that your tests are dependent on the file system being a particular state and is not technically testing the smallest possible thing.

Unit tests must by definition:-

- Test the smallest possible unit
- Not test more than one thing

You would be better off using Cucumbers to test this behaviour or another higher level type of testing. Either that or mock out interaction with the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a loop that does the first check without sleeping (avoiding unnecessary sleeping); if file doesn't exist yet, sleep and repeat for a max of N times, then fail if it hasn't been created in sufficient time.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Dropkick on the unit test strategy. For unit test, if there is any dependency on the environment; try using Mock objects to test the environment specific cases.

See more [Mockito](http://fruzenshtein.com/junit-and-mockito/) and [PowerMock](http://www.thedance.net/~roth/TECHBLOG/powerMock.html) for using a mock framework to create unit test cases.